# Email Routing: Change Actual Receiver, Not Envelope Receiver

Tags: email, routes, google-workspace

I have set up an email routing rule in my Google Workspace (Admin Console): emails sent to `info@example.com` are routed to `hello@instance.xyz`. This works like a charm, except that info@example.com is still listed as the recipient (i.e., the email's `To` header) when they arrive at hello@instance.xyz.

Is there a way to actually rewrite the `To` field with email routing in Google Workspace instead of just changing the envelope recipient, i.e., hide the original recipient in the email after routing?